# Playing sound in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Hi so i have code which gives the answer in form of speech. I am using this code:

```
audio.save("audio.wav") 
sound_file = '/content/audio.wav'
Audio(sound_file, autoplay=True)
```

Now the code plays file all well but if I play in a separate cell. But if I put this code in between my code, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap it in `display()`:

```
from IPython.display import Audio, display

display(Audio(sound_file, autoplay=True))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
from IPython.display import Audio
wn = Audio('path_to_wav_file', autoplay=True)
display(wn)
```